# Does bending drywall weaken it?

Tags: drywall

I bought 1/2" x 4'  x 16' to install on a ceiling with 16" centers. When the lumber yard loaded it they used a fork lift in the center of the 4 sheets to lift it onto my trailer.  As they lifted it the panels flexed so much that it almost bent in half. I couldn't believe that it didn't break.

Now I'm concerned that flexing it that much could weaken it and that it might not be rigid enough to use on the ceiling. Would bending the sheets that much weaken it?"

Comment: FYI, _Sheetrock™_ is a manufacturer of many products, and while "sheetrock" is often used as slang for "gypsum wallboard panel", it's trademarked and doesn't translate well to the international community. I've made some edits.

Comment: If the sheets didn't break, then they are probably OK. When the gypsum core breaks the paper covering cracks with it, making it easy to see. Even though though gypsum panels are sometimes called "rock" they have some flexibility. We have purposely bent dry wall sheets, usually to get them up or down stairway turns, with out damaging the panels. Sheet rock is sometimes installed on archways and arched ceiling, with careful handling.

Comment: 16 foot sheets are pretty floppy... if it didn't snap, it's probably OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gypsum (drywall) panels get most of their strength from the paper face that wraps them. Generally speaking, if this is intact the sheet maintains its integrity. Without the paper, the gypsum inside is soft and brittle.

However, severe bending cracks the gypsum core at frequent intervals. This reduces overall *stiffness* in the sheet, which can mean a wall or ceiling that feels less stout. Occasional cracks in the core don't mean much if they're not closer than the distance between framing members, for example.

Any sheet that has been bent beyond about 45 degrees over say half its length could be considered compromised. Any sheet that's been bent 90 degrees, or that has been bent to a lesser angle but sharply, shouldn't be used, in my opinion, or should be used in less critical areas.

I'd raise the issue with your contractor and have a closer look. The lumber yard should take responsibility for any damaged product.

Comment: I agree with @isherwood if the board bent to a 90 degree bend, then you’d have an issue.